# How to display account address and button text dynamically?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

While using the `@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui` package, I noticed that if you children to `WalletMultiButton`, like so:

```
<WalletMultiButton>Click me!</WalletMultiButton>
```

that, once you connect your wallet, the "Click me!" text will overwrite the account address that is displayed.

I opened this [github issue](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/470) (along with a PR) to see if there was a way to display your own unique button text without overwriting the account address.

Or even better, is there a way to add button text and an account address, which you can manage the CSS of, with the current implementation of `WalletMultiButton`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your own custom text AFAIK the only way doing it is by fetching the account address from the useWallet context

```
const { publicKey } = useWallet();
```

and change

```
<WalletMultiButton>Click me!</WalletMultiButton>
```

to

```
<WalletMultiButton>Click me! {publicKey?.toBase58()}</WalletMultiButton>
```

And to manage the CSS you will have to create a wallet_style.css file where you overwite the style of the WalletMultiButton.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I thought of doing this, but it seems redundant since the source of the component already returns a spliced account address: see line 20 https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/packages/ui/react-ui/src/WalletMultiButton.tsx#L17-L21

Comment: ig `react-ui` is supposed to be simple and we're left to customize it on our own -- hence the use of `children`.

i'll settle on this answer for now and close my issue and PR, thanks again